Using <div contenteditable="true"></div> as an input (in the sense of <input />) to edit content and post onto backend server
I am trying to use  as an input (in the sense of ) to edit content and post the content onto the MySQL backend server by pressing the Save button. I prefer to retain the use  because I want to the content to be style-formattable (bold, italic, bulleted lists, etc.). However, I am unable to do so unless I change  to , which means I cannot keep the formatting options.
Below is my code:
<div className="final-chunk-content" contenteditable="true" onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}></div>
<button className="save-button" onClick={handleClickSaveFinalChunk}>Save</button>

Are there ways to retain  while retaining the function of ?
In addition, just like Google Docs, I want the content inside  to remain there when I reopen the page. How can this be done?
